# How to use the sed command

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a **text** file lets say with the name of "example" and has this data :

```
data:data:data
data:data:data
data:data:data
data:data:data
```

I want to Display the file substituting all instances of the : character with 5 spaces using the SED command I have tried everything but its not working.
how will i do it ?
thanks

Comment: You've tried *what* exactly? Show us.

Comment: Tried everything but still didn't get it to work? Sounds suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `sed` substitution work is required.

```
        sed  's/:/     /g' example.txt
```

Comment: thanks i was just looking for the format